# Only show most recent edits in alerts

Tags: 2013, alert

I have a blog site in which I've set up a weekly email alert on the Posts list but I can't seem to find the sweet spot of what it should show.  Originally I had set it to send me alerts on "All changes" which showed every single edit and deletion turning my supposedly helpful alert email into complete spam.  I then changed it to only send me alerts when "New items are added" which is better but it displays every post at the state of its creation even if it was deleted or edited.

So is there any way to combine these built-in functionalities such that I see a snapshot of the posts that have been created in the past week as they are when the alert is sent out (as opposed to how the post looked when it was created before any edits/deletions)?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should look at workflow for the answer. Send an email based on an attribute you set, could be a "published" flag that you set or any attribute, really. Then you can construct your own email message with the email editor.